# Porque foi reaberta esta pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Esta a ver ontem a noite o site quando vejo esta pergunta [Programar Resta-Um utilizando Método de Monte Carlo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58079/programar-resta-um-utilizando-m%C3%A9todo-de-monte-carlo), fui ver o histórico de edições por causa do comentário do @bfavaretto. 
Reparei que ela foi reaberta pelo @utluiz.

Porque foi reaberta a pergunta se não houve melhoria de conteúdo, só correção de erros de português?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## É uma "lição de casa"

Como alguém que gosta de resolver desafios de programação, mesmo que seja "lição de casa", não tenho problema algum com gente que pede ajuda para resolvê-los também.

Já foi discutido aqui no meta que o fato de uma pergunta ser "lição de casa" não a invalida, pois em programação não há exatamente uma linha divisória entre problemas teóricos e práticas.

Muitos programadores resolveriam tal problema por *hobby* em um site com problemas de programação.

## Ampla?

Sobre ela ser ampla, motivo do primeiro fechamento, **não é verdade**.

Existe um problema específico, a ser solucionado numa linguagem específica, utilizando um algoritmo muito bem especificado.

Ela só parece ampla provavelmente porque os usuários não conhecem o jogo mencionado nem suas regras ou o algoritmo mencionado.

Além disso, a questão original não pedia uma solução completa, mas os passos gerais em alto nível de como a AP poderia começar.

## A pergunta tem problemas

Sim, ela tem problemas. A AP ainda precisaria amadurecer um pouco mais alguns pontos que evidentemente ficam falhos por causa da falta de experiência dela com Java. Também seria interessante ter mais algumas informações.

Ok, eu até concordaria em suspender a questão até que alguns problemas fossem resolvida.

Mas aí está toda a questão: Por que ninguém comentou pedindo mais explicações? Porque ninguém instruiu a AP a postar algum código que tenha feito?

Será que ainda continuamos com essa cultura de "limpar" o site daquilo que não entendemos ao invés de usar o site para sua finalidade original, isto é, **um lugar onde programadores podem ajudar outros programadores através de perguntas e respostas objetivas**.

## E agora, ela não está clara?

Atualmente, a AP editou a pergunta. Ainda tem problemas, a AP ainda não captou a ideia de como o site funciona. Por exemplo, foram adicionados novos pedidos, por exemplo sobre a organização das classes, porém sem informações sobre o código atual.

Mais uma vez: **Será que viramos robôs que só sabem clicar nos botões de fechar da fila de análise? Não dava pra deixar um comentário pelo motivo do fechamento? Ninguém pode editar a pergunta ou instruir a AP a apresentar o código ou ainda a criar uma nova pergunta para novas dúvidas?**

A postagem com os comentários enlatados estão aí para isso.

Outro ponto: não está claro porque está **difícil** de entender ou porque **não é possível** compreender?

## A questão faz da internet um lugar melhor

Mesmo com todos os problemas, que poderiam ser resolvidos em conversa com a AP e uma edição na pergunta, creio que a questão é algo que todos que começam a programar enfrentam quando vão programar um primeiro jogo ou algoritmo.

Quem não teve a dúvida de como representar uma série de elementos em uma determinada estrutura de dados? Na pior das hipóteses, poderíamos dividir a pergunta em várias. A primeira seria: "Como posso representar um tabuleiro em Java?" com a tag `estrutura-de-dados`. Mas não acho que seja necessário, pois não seria a primeira vez que uma pergunta dá origem à outra mais específica.

## Resumo

Bem, foi tudo isso que me fez reabrir a pergunta da primeira vez.

Uma das tarefas que tento fazer como moderador é tentar salvar perguntas da "morte" sempre que possível.

É claro que não consigo fazer isso com todas as perguntas, na verdade tenho tempo hábil de fazer com uma minoria.

Em alguns casos, como este, acabo colocando uma resposta porque após o tempo despendido tentando entender o problema fica óbvio responder, afinal muitas dessas questões são apenas confusas e não realmente amplas ou não claras.

Atualmente, a pergunta está fechada novamente e não concordo nem um pouco com o motivo. Mas não forçarei a reabertura, pois considero que do jeito que ficou vai continuar beneficiando a comunidade.

Comment: Pois eu comentei porque não sou conhecedor, então não fiz nada, mas achei estranho a pergunta ter sido fechada, depois reaberta, depois novamente fechada e a meu ver (que não percebo nada do assunto) a pergunta ficou bastante parecida com a original. Acho que abri bem este post no meta. Parece que quem a reabriu é que percebe realmente do assunto.

Comment: Agora até me deixaste a pensar que eu as vezes, na fila, voto para fechar e nem olho para os comentários. Mas quem pós primeiramente para fechar não devia ser quem faz os comentários? Vou estar mais atento aos comentários.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta que devia ter feito lá em cima era "Porque é que a pergunta foi fechada?". Mas como disse acima, eu como não conhecedor o que me pareceu estranho foi a reabertura. Não sei se me estou a fazer entender.

Comment: @JorgeB. Tens razão que quem votou pela primeira vez torna-se *mais* responsável, afinal inicia todo o processo da fila de análise. Em casos onde o motivo do fechamento não é absurdamente óbvio, é praticamente uma obrigação moral e ética adicionar um comentário. O voto para fechar é válido porque a ideia é que a pergunta pode ser reaberta se houver uma melhora. **Somente** votar para fechar é quase covardia.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não quis dizer que todos os que votam para fechar fazem automaticamente. Sei que é difícil e muitas vezes não se conhece o problema. Eu mesmo tinha dificuldade para analisar isso quando usava a fila antes de ser moderador. Mas seria interessante pelo menos verificar se o AP foi instruído antes de confirmar o fechamento/suspensão. Nos casos onde a pergunta é fechada sem comentários, então chega uma notificação para os moderadores. Este foi o motivo pelo qual atuei especificamente nesse caso.

Comment: @JorgeB. Algumas vezes eu considero que a pergunta foi fechada porque ela estava confusa e "feia" (mal formatada). Então deixando ela mais "bonita" e mais clara sem acrescentar novas informações *poderia* convencer alguns usuários a mudar de ideia. Não é sempre que funciona. Por vezes despendi 15 ou 20 minutos tentando editar uma questão e desisti por achar que não tinha jeito.

Comment: Pois mas percebeste a minha confusão? Se uma pergunta está fechada, quer dizer que os *experts* no assunto a fecharam. Se eles que percebem do assunto a fecharam 2 vezes sem a menor dúvida porque é que tu a abriste foi o que fiquei a pensar. Mas agora depois da tu explicação vejo que não é nada disso e agora está explicado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Certo, está claro agora! :D

Comment: "Nos casos onde a pergunta é fechada sem comentários, então chega uma notificação para os moderadores. Este foi o motivo pelo qual atuei especificamente nesse caso." Não fazia ideia mas é bom isso. Até era uma ideia interessante haver uma fila de analise de perguntas fechadas sem comentários.

Comment: "Por vezes despendi 15 ou 20 minutos tentando editar uma questão e desisti por achar que não tinha jeito." Acontece-me tantas vezes...

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta foi feita por mim a uns dias atras numa fase muito inicial do projeto.

Sou nova no Stackoverflow sim, tentei saber como fazer uma pergunta de forma a parecer o mais clara possivel,  obvio que nao estou a espera que alguem responda de imediato com codigo ou uma solucao imediata, nao faz sentido.
 Mais tarde apercebi-me que a pergunta tinha sido editada por nao ser clara e por haver erros no meu portugues, pensei que fosse esse o problema e editei.

Acerca do tema da minha pergunta, e um Metodo de Monte Carlo e um metodo que ja foi estudado e analisado muitas vezes e aplicado em varios jogos, mas nao para o jogo que estou a tentar analisar, pelo menos que eu tivesse conhecimento, dai a minha confusao em passar o algoritmo, que consegui entender, para Java

Pelo que li a pergunta foi fechada duas vezes por ser ampla demais, mas nao recebi nenhum comentario a pedir mais clarificacao o que achei estranho. Alterei a pergunta, de forma a parecer mais clara e so nao adicionei mais informacao ou tentativas minhas porque naquela altura era o que tinha no momento e como disse ainda e uma fase inicial do projeto.
Quando se faz qualquer especie de projeto comeca-se no basico, estrutura, pesquisa, recursos etc..

Passado uns dias ja tenho um pouco de mais conhecimento e mais ideias acerta do projeto. Poderia alterar a pergunta de novo com dados muito mais especificos, mas duvido que leve a algum lado.
Sim tens razao, se a pergunta foi fechada duas vezes por alguma coisa e, e confusa, ampla, e com poucos dados, mas com a pouca informacao que forneci, recebi uma reposta que condizia com o que eu queria, pedir mais informacao ou clarificacao por parte dos utilizadores que estao interessados em ajudar talvez fosse mais sensato. Pelo menos e isso que faço quando alguem me faz uma pergunta que nao entendo de inicio.

Acho bem que tenhas levantado este problema, e assim que se fazem mudancas e se aprende.
Eu creio que isto pode servir como uma especie de licao para todos, estamos aqui todos para aprender e partilhar conhecimento, uma atitude menos "nazi" por parte de muitos utilizadores que tenho visto no SO tanto Portugues como Ingles beneficiaria a comunidade.

PS: Agradeco imenso ao administrador por ter editado e respondido a minha pergunta, Obrigado